# Call Website resource through Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

I have one scenario in which i have to call the Website from Windows Service schedule at specific time. I need to get some HTML resources and then send it to Email using Windows service. Is their any possibility to call the web resource through windows service ? I am open to any implementation with in .NET framework.

Regards

Comment: Did you take a look at HttpClient class ? you can make http calls to your website(which can return the markup) from your windows service code.

Comment: Is there a way to get the PDF from HTML because i have to send an email attached with PDF.

Comment: Maybe simpler to made & debug is general application running from windows Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

> have one scenario in which i have to call the Website from Windows Service schedule at specific time. I need to get some HTML resources and then send it to Email using Windows service.

This is harder than it sounds. The components that render HTML into a viewable web page all expect a desktop, which a Windows Service doesn't have.

Then you still need to render the HTML into a PDF, which is something else that there is no native support for in .Net. You would need a 3rd party library like GhostScript or one from Adobe (don't remember the name, but it's expensive).

When you do it from the desktop, Adobe Acrobat is doing the heavy lifting, but that's not available from a service because Acrobat also requires a desktop.

If you can find a way to render HTML without having a desktop or interactive session, you can then render the HTML into a PDF with Ghostscript.Net and system.net.mail.

If this doesn't actually need to be a service, it would be an afternoon's work in VB.Net or C#, however if you really need it to be a Windows Service, it's going to be very difficult.

**New Info**

Apparently PhantomJS can run headless and render web pages (see link below)

Comment: Author did not write, how complicated are "httml resources", ajaxified etc... Maybe You are right, but this depends on complication & method. C# has few pdf libraries like iText

Comment: I was explaining an alternate method that would actually work and could be written in a reasonable amount of time. Rendering HTML inside a Windows Service is going to be a nightmare. There are no Windows libraries I'm aware of that do this because they all require a desktop session. I don't beleive iText is callable from a .net service either.

Comment: Given the way the question was worded, I'm reasonably certain that the author didn't understand what was involved. A desktop application called from a scheduled task would do exactly what was requested, with less than a day's worth of work. The service would probably *never* do what was requested because rendering a faithful image of modern web page requires a current browser like Chrome or Firefox or IE, none of which can be called from a Windows Service.

Comment: @PushfPopf Actually i need to schedule email daily. That's why i need the windows service which can be scheduled. I can't use windows application because there is no interaction from user as part of the requirement. I have to generate the PDF from service which should contains the HTML contents in it.

Comment: The task scheduler can run desktop apps. The only "catch" is that if it wants user input, the task will hang. HTML has evolved so quickly that I don't think there's anything that you can run from a service to render HTML into anything that can be put into a PDF and give you the type of output users expect. I've done extensive work with automated document conversion to PDF and never found anything that did a good job of HTML -> PDF, except actual browsers. If you find anything, please update your thread.

Comment: You might be able to use PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/). It loosk like it might do the trick, although I've never used it.